# Select columns for ORDER BY only, not returning them in the results

Tags: mysql

So I have a complicated `INSERT` query which puts information into a relational table based on information pulled from another table and with given variables.

Here's the query:

```
INSERT INTO relational (class_id, teacher_id, student_id)
VALUES (
    (SELECT `id`,
        (`name` = "John Smith") as exact_score,
        (`name` RLIKE "[[:<:]]John Smith[[:>:]]") as reg_score,
        (MATCH (`name`) AGAINST ("John Smith")) as match_score
    FROM `teachers`
    WHERE (`title` RLIKE "[[:<:]]John Smith[[:>:]]" || MATCH (`title`) AGAINST ("John Smith"))
    ORDER BY
        CASE WHEN exact_score = 1 THEN exact_score END DESC,
        CASE WHEN reg_score > 1 THEN reg_score END DESC,
        CASE WHEN reg_score = 0 AND exact_score = 0 THEN match_score END DESC),
1, 1);
```

The regex is required because the name might be `Mr. John Smith` or `John Smith PH.d`, and the match is required because the name might be `jon smith` When the stored name is actually just `John Smith`.

The select query yields the results I am looking for 90% of the time, but the only real *column* that I need from it is `id`. The problem I'm running into is with the INSERT's expected column count vs. the column count that is returned by the query.

Right now the INSERT basically looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO relational (class_id, teacher_id, student_id) VALUES ({{returned id (desired)}}, {{exact score (undesired)}}, {{reg score (undesired)}}, {{match score (undesired)}}, 1, 1);
```

The last `1, 1` is provided by variables.

My question is, is there a way to select columns for the sake of ORDER BY, but then to omit them from the results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the column is defined in a table/view, you can use it in `ORDER BY` and omit it from results. But in your case, you are using *calculated columns* in `ORDER BY`, so if you want to omit these columns, you have to replace them in `ORDER BY` with corresponding formula, e.g.

```
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN (`name` = "John Smith") = 1 THEN (`name` = "John Smith") END DESC
    -- etc...
```

I think this is not a good solution. Instead, It's better to use subquery:

```
INSERT INTO relational (class_id, teacher_id, student_id)
SELECT id,1,1 FROM
    (SELECT `id`,
        (`name` = "John Smith") as exact_score,
        (`name` RLIKE "[[:<:]]John Smith[[:>:]]") as reg_score,
        (MATCH (`name`) AGAINST ("John Smith")) as match_score
    FROM `teachers`
    WHERE (`title` RLIKE "[[:<:]]John Smith[[:>:]]" || MATCH (`title`) AGAINST ("John Smith"))
    ORDER BY
        CASE WHEN exact_score = 1 THEN exact_score END DESC,
        CASE WHEN reg_score > 1 THEN reg_score END DESC,
        CASE WHEN reg_score = 0 AND exact_score = 0 THEN match_score END DESC)
    AS t1;
```